# trying to set sublime-keymap, getting a "Error trying to parse file" message

Tags: xml, json, sublimetext2

On this page: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/key-bindings it says that the sublime-keymap files are XML files, and can be configured with that syntax. However, opening up the `Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` file, I see only the following:

```
[
]
```

Which suggests that this is not XML, but in fact JSON. Furthermore, copying and pasting in the following lines from the above page:

```
<binding key="ctrl+t,u" command="upperCase"/>
<binding key="ctrl+t,l" command="lowerCase"/>
```

and then saving the file, I get an error:

```
Error trying to parse file: Unexpected trailing characters in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap:2:1
```

so I'm guessing that, in fact, the sublime-keymap settings are not XML but JSON. So maybe the docs are out of date? Anyway, how can I set up a command like the one I put in above? I want a command that converts all selected text to upper case.

Thanks!

Comment: could you take a look at the proposed answers and select one that works for you please?

Answer (score 1):

Open the default keymap to see the correct format for bindings: *Preferences -> Key bindings - Default*:

```
[
  { "keys": ["ctrl+t","u"], "command": "upper_case" },
  { "keys": ["ctrl+t","l"], "command": "lower_case" }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that page seems to be out of date. The [unofficial documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html) is much more informative (see also [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html)):

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+n"], "command": "new_window" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+o"], "command": "prompt_open_file" }
]
```

So it's obvious how to write what you need:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+t","u"], "command": "uppercase" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+t","l"], "command": "lowercase" }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a built-in short cut in ST2 - Ctrl+K,Ctrl+U (hit Ctrl+K quickly followed by Ctrl+U), so you could save yourself the trouble of defining a new keymap. As @d_rail has pointed out, you could verify this by looking at Preferences->Key Bindings->Default